# jQuery: Div interchange with jQuery

Tags: jquery

There is a button on a page with value "button1". When pressed, it must delete itself and add new button with value "button2". When "button2" is pressed, it must delete itself and add "button1" back. Kinda infinite loop.

I know that it can be done just by changing the value of a button or at least using "detach()" function, but it is the simplest case of my problem in a website that I'm currently trying to implement where I must interchange two "div"s full of data by buttons.

So, back to the problem, the thing is while "button1" works fine, "button2" does nothing. A bit of help will be appreciated.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "script.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div id = "div1">
            <input type = button id = "button1" value = "button1" />
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $("#button1").click (function() {
        $("body").append ("<div id = 'div2'></div>");
        $("#div2").append ("<input type = button id = 'button2' value = 'button2' />");
        $("#div1").remove();
    });

    $("#button2").click (function() {
        $("body").append ("<div id = 'div1'></div>");
        $("#div1").append ("<input type = button id = 'button1' value = 'button1' />");
        $("#div2").remove();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#button2` is not responding to the *click* because it is non-existent at the time of binding the `click()` event.

You can solve this by binding with `.on()`

```
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function() {
    ....
});

$(document).on('click', '#button2', function() {
    ....
});
```

Comment: thanks, i've started to learn recently, pretty easy to fall on such silly mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Change to use `.on` since elements are being dynamically added:

```
$(document).on("click", "#button1", function() {
    $("body").append ("<div id = 'div2'></div>");
    $("#div2").append ("<input type = button id = 'button2' value = 'button2' />");
    $("#div1").remove();
});

$(document).on("click", "#button2", function() {
    $("body").append ("<div id = 'div1'></div>");
    $("#div1").append ("<input type = button id = 'button1' value = 'button1' />");
    $("#div2").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to attach a click handler to an element that doesn't exist initially, and it won't get attached to your dynamically created element.

Try using the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) jQuery function, or in earlier jQuery versions, the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function, like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#button1", function() {
    (...)
});

$(document).on("click", "#button2", function() {
    (...)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `.on` jQuery function. Since you are creating the div via JavaScript and it isn't already in the DOM.

Same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207393/1165441

`.live` is deprecated so you can ignore unless you are using an older version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

When manipulating the DOM the event handlers that are attached to your buttons are not attached again. You have a similar problem after the page loads - button2 does not exist and there is no click event for it.

If you regenerate the events after DOM manipulation it will work:

```
function set_events() {
    $("#button1").click (function() {
        $("body").append ("<div id = 'div2'></div>");
        $("#div2").append ("<input type = button id = 'button2' value = 'button2' />");
        $("#div1").remove();
        set_events();
    });

    $("#button2").click (function() {
        $("body").append ("<div id = 'div1'></div>");
        $("#div1").append ("<input type = button id = 'button1' value = 'button1' />");
        $("#div2").remove();
        set_events();
    });
}

$(document).ready (function() {
    set_events();
});
```